# Azure adding end points on new portal

Tags: azure

I am setting up a lamp webserver on azure.i know the way we used in classic panel.but in the new azure portal panel nothing shown related to adding end points

How to add end points on new azure portal?

Comment: Please see my answer on ServerFault ([link](http://serverfault.com/a/737796/99269)) which shows exactly where the settings are, in both classic and new portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Network Security Groups to open ports for your VM. You can consult [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal) to achieve that.

Comment: if the answer helps, you should mark it as an answer ;)